# Why would my code not be suggested as an answer in hints for Q4 of Codecademy JavaScript Mini Linter Project?

Tags: javascript, foreach, iteration, higher-order-functions

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

let storyWords = story.split(' ');

//console.log(storyWords.length);

let betterWords = storyWords.filter(function(word) {
  return !unnecessaryWords.includes(word)
});

//console.log(betterWords);
```

Q4:

"There is an array of words called `overusedWords`. These are words overused in this `story`. You want to let the user of your program know how many times they have used these overused words. There are two ways to achieve this. Try it on your own first. If you need help, consult the hint."

Hint:

1. You can iterate over the `betterWords` array three separate times (once for each of the words in the `overusedWords` array). Create a variable that represents the total times that word appears. Add `1` to the variable every time the current word is the same as that word.
2. You can make this simpler by using one `if`, and two `else if` statements in the function code block of your iterator. That way, you can gather the counts of all three overused words at one time.

Without using the hints, my initial code was

```
let countOverusedWords = storyWords.filter(function(word) {
  return overusedWords.includes(word)
});

console.log(countOverusedWords.length);
```

I think my code answers the question but should I have logged the overused words to the console within the countOverusedWords function body?

I have been shown a different way to answer the question but not given an explanation how it works

```
let overusedWordCount = [];
overusedWords.forEach(word => {
  overusedWordCount[word] = 0;
})

overusedWords.forEach(overusedWord => {
  betterWords.forEach(word => {
    if (word === overusedWord) {
      overusedWordCount[overusedWord]++;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to remove commas, dots etc. before splitting.

Comment: Your approach says how many times all overused word has appeared in your string, whereas it actually seems like they want you to output how many times _each_ word has occurred,  eg: "really" occurred 2 times, "very" occurred X times, etc.

Comment: `overusedWordCount` ... see how that contains a count of each of the overused words ... and your code just how many of the overused words were used

Comment: Your last code block creates an array `[]`, this really should be an object `{}`. You can read more about objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#description) and how you can create _keys/properties_ within the object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have now used storyWords.forEach with if else statements in the function body and I've logged variables countReally, countVery and countBasically to the console individually